# Push notification issue on Production environment

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, ios10

I have an app ,that is live on App Store, which uses **Push notification** as one of its features. While using development mode device token  is successfully created but when I use production provisioning profile device token is not generated.I am using old production provisioning profile on which the app is live. So should I create new **Production Provisioning Profile** or am I doing something wrong.